# std::unordered_multiset exception iterating bucket

Tags: c++, unordered-multiset

My test case is the one shown below:

```
std::size_t t(const int &i) { return i | 0b01010101010101010101010101010101; }

int main()
{
    std::unordered_multiset<int, decltype(&t)> um(100, t);
    um.insert(9872934);
    um.insert(9024582);
    um.insert(2589429);
    um.insert(2254009);
    um.insert(3254082);
    um.insert(3945820);
    um.insert(8347893);

    auto intf = t(9872934);
    for (auto cb = um.begin(intf), end = um.end(intf); cb != end; ++cb)
    {
        std::cout << *cb;
    }
};
```

Debugging with Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 v17.1.2 an exception is thrown constructing the iterator; first I thougth that the hash function (`t`) could be the one to blame so I've tried this:

```
std::unordered_multiset<int> um; // no custom hash, just multiset of integers...
um.insert(9872934);
um.insert(9024582);
um.insert(2589429);
um.insert(2254009);
um.insert(3254082);
um.insert(3945820);
um.insert(8347893);

auto intf = t(9872934);
for (auto cb = um.begin(intf), end = um.end(intf); cb != end; ++cb)
{
    std::cout << *cb;
}
```

But it behaves the same way, even in online compilers ([check it out](https://tio.run/##fZDNboMwEITP@Cm2qhRBQyuHHwUHwqtEYJzIEhhkrw9tyrNTOxyicKh8sb6ZWY2GT9Mn7xt1W5Z3qXhvOwGVVaPuhBbdxQisyVOQo0EtmqEmxGB3Ohn5Iy4IGPJRGQSpEHYygjtogVYrkPALtKWH/18JMyE@OzRShRG5k@Bx/VljsD1K16Vyrhg6wXv8nkS4w6gGO4QHSmPAqCSBHb6kMkJjyIpjwtJsA2mS5UXyCpO8YFnCNjDJM0o3MPVwG0@ZP0lfYZFmx4KlDpKgsTj6aa5whpde11FD@FB56zSXbsXNLeC9UQxCdSt1n5WV3vh29koJ@z1vIxK4sda1@GgRqgo@eOtuz2Qul@UP)). What I'm missing? How should I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to the `begin(bucket)` function is the bucket number not the key.

You need use `bucket` to get the bucket number that corresponds to the key

```
auto intf = um.bucket(t(9872934)); <<<====
for (auto cb = um.begin(intf), end = um.end(intf); cb != end; ++cb)
{
    std::cout << *cb;
}
```